# R: Adding a Customized Scale

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am working with the R programming language.

I have the following graph:

```
library(ggplot2)

df1 <- data.frame(x1 = rnorm(100, 100, 100))
df2 <- data.frame(x1 = rnorm(100, 1000, 1000))
df3 <- data.frame(x1 = rnorm(100, 10000, 10000))
df = data.frame(rbind(df1,df2, df3))
df$id = 1:nrow(df)
df$x1 = log(df$x1)


ggplot(df, aes(x1)) +
  geom_histogram() +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 16, by = 1))
```

**My Question:** I want to keep the same graph but add a custom x-axis to this graph with the following labels. That is, keep the natural log of the variable - but have the x-axis with custom labels.

For example, suppose I (whimsically) only wanted the following labels - but posted in the correct positions (i.e. 100 = log of what x1, 200 = log of what x1, etc):

```
c("0", "100", "200", "300", "400", ">500")
```

Is it possible to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: `scale_x_continuous(breaks = log(labels), labels = labels)` where `labels <- 100*0:5`?

Comment: You could alternatively skip the `df$x1 = log(df$x1)` line and instead use `scale_x_continuous(trans = scales::log_trans(), breaks = labels)` for a similar result. (I thought I saw a question explaining a subtle shift between them, but I can't recall it.)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible to add custom labels to the x-axis of a ggplot graph. You can use the `scale_x_continuous()` function again, but this time, you need to specify the breaks and labels arguments to control the placement and labeling of your x-axis ticks.

Since you want labels like `"0", "100", "200", "300", "400", ">500"` at the correct log positions, you need to calculate the corresponding natural logarithms (ln) of these values and set these as the breaks and then set the labels as your custom labels.

natural logarithm of 0 is undefined, but it approaches negative infinity. If you want to use "0" as a label you will have to define an appropriate point to represent this in your specific data context.

Here is how you can do it:

```
# Calculate the corresponding log values for your labels.
log_vals <- log(c(1, 100, 200, 300, 400, 500)) 

# Custom labels
custom_labels <- c("0", "100", "200", "300", "400", ">500")

ggplot(df, aes(x1)) +
  geom_histogram() +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = log_vals, labels = custom_labels)
```

I replaced `"0"` with `"1"` for the log transformation because `log(0)` is undefined. This code will show `"0"` at the point where `log(1) = 0`, and `">500"` at the point where `log(500) = 6.21` (approximately).